# How to integrate JavaFX with OSGI

Tags: javafx, osgi

```
// code to start bundle   
@start  
public void startBundle() {
    Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(() -> {
                    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
                    this.getClass().getClassLoader());
                    launch();
                }).start();
}
```

Bundle is active state after i adding all dependency manager annotations but no screen is displayed.

Comment: Where is this code? What interface does it implement? How is it invoked? What is this `@start` annotation and where does it come from? FAR too little information here to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have released a couple of first Early Access versions of [Drombler FX](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/) - the modular application framework for JavaFX.

It's based on OSGi and Maven (POM-first). It integrates OSGi and JavaFX out-of-the-box. Maybe you find it useful. The application framework is Open Source.

There is also a [tutorial](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/index.html#tutorial) with a [Getting Started](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/getting-started.html#gettingStarted) page.